# Java BoxLayout problems with JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, boxlayout

I have a JFrame the content pane of which contains two JPanels. Both of them have a BoxLayout. In both of the panels I have added a table in a panel and then a panel with buttons. The panels which contains the two tables at the bottom do not wrap around the tables appropriately. What can I do to fix this problem[image]

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: Without an example it's difficult to help, but have you really tried using setPreferredSize(Dimension d)  on the two Tables?

Comment: @navy1978 I fixed it myself. It was a silly mistake.